# passing blank value in name field but it doesn't show error by using Binding Result and Javaxvalidation api

Tags: java, pom.xml

I am passing blank value in name field but it doesn't show error.
It simply run and stores the value in database.
But i want when i pass blank in name field then it prints error message in consle before saving entity to database
there is my code. i tried by changing the position of binding result and changing dependency.

Controller code

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public String register(@Valid @ModelAttribute User user, final BindingResult result,@RequestParam(value = "agreed", defaultValue = "false") boolean agreed, Model model,  HttpSession session) {
    
    try {
        //here error should print
        System.out.println(result.hasErrors());
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
     
        if(agreed) {
            session.setAttribute("message", new Message("registered successfully", "alert-success"));
            user.setActive("true");
            user.setRole("USER_ROLE");
            model.addAttribute("user", user);
            System.out.println(result.hasErrors());
                if(result.hasErrors()) {
                    System.out.println(result);
                }
             
             this.userservice.saveUser(user);
            return "signup";
        }
        session.setAttribute("message", new Message("agree terms and conditions", "alert-danger"));
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "signup";
        
    }catch (Exception e) {
        session.setAttribute("message", new Message("error "+e.toString(), "alert-success"));
        return "signup";
    }
}
```

user file

```
package com.smart.entities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "myusers")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "it is mandatory")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "length of name must be betweeen 3 nd 20.")
    private String name;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String about;
    private String role;
    private String active;
    private String image;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    
    public User() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public User(int id, String name, String email, String password, String about, String role, String active,
            String image, List<Contact> contacts) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.about = about;
        this.role = role;
        this.active = active;
        this.image = image;
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + ", password=" + password + ", about=" + about
                + ", role=" + role + ", active=" + active + ", image=" + image + ", contacts=" + contacts + "]";
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getAbout() {
        return about;
    }

    public void setAbout(String about) {
        this.about = about;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(String active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public List<Contact> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

    public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }
    
    
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SmartContactManager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SmartContactManager</name>
    <description>contact project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Try using your IDE's debugger to find out what this code is actually doing